# Message "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the XPath expression" using sendKeys

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am having trouble trying to upload a file using Selenium. I am not able to use the sendKeys() function to pass the path due to the browse button not having an input tag. It's written in Angular.

Here's the browse button element:

```
<a id="attachmentUpload-browse0" name="attachmentUpload-browse0" ng-click="clickBrowse($index)" class="btn-pri" xpath="1"></a>
```

I did find an input tag right below the code above in the source, but I am getting errors when trying to use `.sendKeys()`.

```
<input type="file" id="attachmentUpload-file0" name="attachmentUpload-file0" fileread="$parent.attachments[$index].fileData" class="attachmentUpload-inputfile ng-isolate-scope" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().onFileChange(this)" style="" xpath="1">
```

Edit: Error when using .sendKeys() to input tag

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@id="attachmentUpload-file0"]// because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//input[@id="attachmentUpload-file0"]//' is not a valid XPath expression.
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[@id="attachmentUpload-file0"]//}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:319)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:421)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:311)
at com.ibm.esh.o2c.art.Tester.runTest(Tester.java:61)
at com.ibm.esh.o2c.art.Tester.main(Tester.java:70)
```

Error when using a tag for attachmentUpload-browse0:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

Comment: Update the question with the _error stack trace_ you see while using the `<input>` tag

Comment: Will do. May take a bit. Selenium is acting very strange over past hour, page loads are taking forever. I see "Connecting" on bottom of browser for 2 minutes (loads in Chrome normally nearly instant). Was not having that issue in the days prior.

Comment: Okay got it up there now.

Comment: Your code trials please? Perhaps you should try with `xpath` as **//input[@id="attachmentUpload-file0"]**

Comment: element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=\"attachmentUpload-file0\"]//"));
    element.sendKeys("test");

Comment: Try to use only `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='attachmentUpload-file0']")); element.sendKeys("test");`

Comment: That appeared to work.

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='attachmentUpload-file0']")).sendKeys(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/test1.csv");

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@id="attachmentUpload-file0"]// because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//input[@id="attachmentUpload-file0"]//' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

...implies that your XPath expression was not a valid one.

You can use the following line of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='attachmentUpload-file0']")).sendKeys("test");
```