# Selenium java can't get html text

Tags: java, html, selenium, gettext

I have this HTML code:

```
<span id="slotTotal">
    <span id="slotUsed">4</span>
          /16
</span>
```

I want to get text /16 but when I try:

```
slotTot = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='slotTotal']")).getText();
```

I get this Exception:
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector while trying to locate an element

How can I fix that? (If I get 4/16 is good too...) thanks in advance

Comment: Does this solution help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49909051/11700321

Comment: No sorry :/ It just says it's an invalid xpath, but I get the xpath from chrome, and if it is an invalid xpath I don't know what's the valid one

Comment: Have you tried: `slotTot = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='slotTotal']")).getText();` ?

Comment: Have you tried  String getText = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].value;",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='slotTotal']")));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get text of SlotUsed**

```
String slotUsed= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='slotUsed']")).gettext();
System.out.println("Value of used slot"+slotUsed);
```

**To get SubTotal** (subtotal is part of first span element)

```
  String total=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@id='slotTotal']")).getText();
  System.out.println("Total"+total);
```

Comment: please check upddated solution

Comment: is it working for you ? if yes then please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
String slotTot = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space(@id='slotUsed']")).gettext();
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xpath` utilize `following-sibling`:

```
//span[@id='slotUsed']/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Like below:

```
String slotTot = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='slotUsed']/following-sibling::text()[1]")).getText();
```